# Why does one ADO.NET Excel query work and another does not?

Tags: excel, ado.net, ado

I'm working on a SharePoint workflow, and the first step requires me to open an Excel workbook and read two things: a range of categories (from a range named, conveniently enough, `Categories`) and a category index (in the named range `CategoryIndex`). `Categories` is a list of roughly 100 cells, and `CategoryIndex` is a single cell.

I'm using ADO.NET to query the workbook

```
string connectionString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    "Data Source=" + temporaryFileName + ";" +
    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\"";

OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
connection.Open();

OleDbCommand categoryIndexCommand = new OleDbCommand();
categoryIndexCommand.Connection = connection;
categoryIndexCommand.CommandText = "Select * From CategoryIndex";

OleDbDataReader indexReader = categoryIndexCommand.ExecuteReader();
if (!indexReader.Read())
    throw new Exception("No category selected.");
object indexValue = indexReader[0];
int categoryIndex;
if (!int.TryParse(indexValue.ToString(), out categoryIndex))
    throw new Exception("Invalid category manager selected");

OleDbCommand selectCommand = new OleDbCommand();
selectCommand.Connection = connection;
selectCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Categories";
OleDbDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (!reader.HasRows || categoryIndex >= reader.RecordsAffected)
    throw new Exception("Invalid category/category manager selected.");

connection.Close();
```

Don't judge the code itself too harshly; it's been through a lot. Anyway, the first command never executes correctly. It doesn't throw an exception. It just returns an empty data set. (`HasRows` is `true`, and `Read()` returns `false`, but there is no data there) The second command works perfectly. These are both named ranges.

They are populated differently, however. There's a web service call that fills up `Categories`. Those values are displayed in a dropdown box. The selected index goes into `CategoryIndex`. After hours of banging my head, I decided to write a couple of lines of code so that the dropdown's value goes into a different cell, then I copy the value using a couple of lines of C# into `CategoryIndex`, so that the data is set identically. That turned out to be a blind alley, too.

Am I missing something? Why would one query work perfectly and the other fail to return any data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the issue. Excel was apparently unable to parse the value in the cell, so it was returning nothing. What I had to do was adjust the connection string to the following:

```
string connectionString =
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
    "Data Source=" + temporaryFileName + ";" +
    "Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\"";
```

It would have been helpful if it would have thrown an exception or given *any* indication of why it was failing, but that's beside the point now. The option `IMEX=1` tells Excel to treat all values as strings only. I'm quite capable of parsing my own integers, thankyouverymuch, Excel, so I didn't need its assistance.